# performant click and double click in jquery

Tags: jquery, double-click

The intent of this code was create a performant `click` and `double click` action,
but it actually work very bad... It is not very performant at all, so I would like to know a better way to do it

In this way I completely lost the sensibility of the single click, and now it is only delayed,

and also the double click is not very brilliant..

```js
var DELAY = 150, clicks = 0, timer = null;
$(function(){
    $('button').on("click", function(e){
        clicks++;
        if(clicks === 1) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('button').html("Single Click");
                clicks = 0;
            }, DELAY);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('button').html("Double Click");
            clicks = 0;
        }
    })
    .on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
button {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click Me</button>
```

Comment: 150ms of delay is not a lot at all. You should increase that. Lot of users do a double-click not that fast. Maybe between 500ms and 800ms ?

Comment: @Dean Try the button in the snippet.. You will see that it responds very slowly to the clicks! I really hope there are other better solutions to do that

Comment: In jQuery there https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/ who's good

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks mostly fine. One of the problems of dealing with clicks and double clicks is you'll have to show one result before the other. Otherwise, you have to impose a delay for people who single click.

The code below simply moved your `$('button').html("Single Click");` outside of the timer function, so it will make the button respond immediately instead of waiting to see if the user is double clicking.

```js
var DELAY = 350, clicks = 0, timer = null;
$(function(){
    $('button').on("click", function(e){
        clicks++;
        $('button').html("Single Click");
        if(clicks === 1) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                clicks = 0;
            }, DELAY);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('button').html("Double Click");
            clicks = 0;
        }
    })
    .on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
button {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is great, I'd say there's not really a way to improve this as far as logic goes.  Only way would be to lengthen `delay` so it's more accessible.  Old people sometimes click mouses slower... :P

Your delay:
http://jsfiddle.net/0928paqh/1/

Longer delay:
http://jsfiddle.net/0928paqh/2/

Long enough for slower users, but not long enough to be annoying to anyone.

Comment: The problem with that code is that I completely lost the sensibility of the single click, and now it is only delayed